# Any security risks using Facebook login

Tags: facebook, security, api

A client of mine that is going to be selling photographs where customers can buy using Visa card payments wants to have his users have the ability to have thier accounts linked to their facebook login.

This way they can log into the site using their Facebook account, much like this site allows you.

Are there any security risks with this?

Credit card details will not be held/stored in any form and the payment will be handled by a company that deals with the transactions at the time the purchase is made.

Regards and TIA
John

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, not really.  Facebook login uses the OAuth 2.0 protocol which is widely used and accepted.  You can [read more here](http://oauth.net/2/) if you're really concerned.

Comment: Thanks all. Answered all my concerns.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds to me like the primary concern of handling credit card details will be mitigated by the fact that such details will not be stored.

The primary question seems to me to be: If a user's account were breached in some way via OpenId/OAuth Facebook login, what kind of damage could a malicious user do to the photography site?

1. Change profile details?
2. Post comments?
3. Order photos (but would still need to enter valid credit card details)?

Let's imagine the worst case scenario; Is the amount of damage a malicious user could do acceptable to you (your users and your credibility) for the type of website that you're running?

Facebook uses [OAuth 2.0](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OAuth) for authentication and is currently a standard way of providing third party authentication.